# Pandas: add column based on logic across the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
   A          B          C
0  20200608  20200507   202006
1  20200608  20200630   202006
2  20200608  20200701   202006
3  20200508  20200401   202005
4  20200508  20200507   202005
5  20200508  20200508   202005
6  20200408  20203030   202004
7  20200308  20200601   202003
```

I have a function
get_previous_month(202006) -> 202005

I want to update my dataframe to add a bool in "D" if the date in B > the Date in A for the YYYYMM -1

All the dates in column A, for the same YYYYMM in C, will be the same

ex: in Row 0, column C is 202006, the prior YYYYMM is 202005. 20200507 is not greater than 20200508

```
   A          B          C        D
0  20200608  20200507   202006   False
1  20200608  20200630   202006   True
2  20200608  20200701   202006   True
3  20200508  20200401   202005   False
4  20200508  20200507   202005   True
5  20200508  20200508   202005   True
6  20200408  20203030   202004   True
7  20200308  20200601   202003   Null
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?  I'd create a temporary pd.Series and populate it using your `get_previous_month()` function, then do the comparison and assign the result to the new column `D`.

Comment: Could you explain better what is the constraint in the dates? What's the role of the previous moth function?You can notice that the current date format you are using has already a lexicographical order consistent with time order. This means that comparing the strings will already yield correct time comparison.

Comment: - column A is a publication date for the row.
 - column B is a date of some observation
 - row B contains data that was already stated in a previous publication
 - I want to indicate which rows contain data that occurred after the prior publication date

Comment: @ john - I working on it now - but I'm new to dataframes - thought I'd ask for some help while I'm working it out - I'll probably start with something not ideal - iterrows() and try to improve - thought by asking I'd get more familiar with how to use pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what I have ...

```
        is_current = {}

        cutoff = lambda x: pd.unique(df[df['C'] == add_months(x, -1) ]['A']).tolist()

        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            row_cutoff = cutoff(row['C'])
            if row_cutoff:
                is_current[i] = int(row['B']) > int(row_cutoff[0])
            else:
                is_current[i] = None

        is_current = [is_current.get(a) for a in range(len(is_current.keys()))]
        df['D'] = is_current
        df.reset_index(drop=True)
```